# Ecobee thermostat warning with heat pump

Tags: thermostat

Has anyone experienced this on an ecobee thermostat:
Ecobee Auxiliary Heat Running Too Long
I have a heat pump in the house

Comment: The auxiliary heat kicks in when the heat pump can not provide enough heat, when the out door temp falls below 40 F

Comment: Sorry.  I meant heat pump

Comment: The issue is that my aux heat didn't kick in all that much on my old thermostat. I set the minimum outdoor temp to 35F which was the same as on my old thermostat. Not sure why the aux heat would be on for more than 3 hours with outside temperature greater than 35F

Comment: Maybe you should read this https://support.ecobee.com/s/articles/Threshold-settings-for-ecobee-thermostats

Comment: Get a competent heat pump, not 1970's garbage tech (which some unethical companies will still happily sell you today) that won't run below freezing or even near-but-above freezing.

Comment: Thanks Ruskes. That article was perfect